# Valores por defecto al crear un Array?

Tags: array, c

Muy buenas.

Me gustaria saber con que valores son inicializados los vector/Array al momento de crearlos (Especificamente en C). O si las posiciones permanecen vacias hasta que sean llenadas.

```
int contadoresDig[10];

for (int i = 0; i < lengthPiNumbrs; i++)
{
    switch (piNumbrs[i])
    {
    case 0:
        contadoresDig[0] += 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        contadoresDig[1] += 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        contadoresDig[2] += 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        contadoresDig[3] += 1;
        break;
    case 4:
        contadoresDig[4] += 1;
        break;
    case 5:
        contadoresDig[5] += 1;
        break;
    case 6:
        contadoresDig[6] += 1;
        break;
    case 7:
        contadoresDig[7] += 1;
        break;
    case 8:
        contadoresDig[8] += 1;
        break;
    case 9:
        contadoresDig[9] += 1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, donde cuento la cantidad de apariciones de cada dígito de un array con los numeros de pi, si no inicializo las 10 posiciones con cero, el resultado es muy grande y hasta negativo.

Busque por varios foros y no encuentro nada sobre el tema. Seria de mucha ayuda si pueden darme una idea.

Saludos.

Comment: Las variables acaban siendo una simple posición en memoria. Entiendase simple como un grupo de bytes en la memoria RAM. Esas posiciones de memoria son dinamicas en función de los espacios de memoria asignados por el nucleo del OS cuando un programa los solicita. Lo normal es que esten vacios (a 0) pero si el OS libera espacios y los vuelve a asignar, cosa muy común en sistemas de baja RAM, es muy probable que el byte tenga un valor distinto a 0. Negativo o no está en función de como tu programa procesa los datos. Un 245 es positivo si trabajamos en enteros sin signo pero será un -11 con signos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En C, **toda variable *automática* sin inicializar tiene un valor indefinido y, por ende, aleatorio**. Esto aplica a cualquier tipo de variable:

- *simple*: `int x;`
- Estructuras: `struct Algo { int x; } instance;`
- Formaciones (tanto de datos simples como de estructuras): `struct { int x } array[10];`

En todos los casos, el contenido queda **sin especificar**. Eso quiere decir que *puede* que el compilador las rellene con algún valor, o *puede* que contengan un valor aleatorio.

Fíjate que indico *en variables automáticas*; es decir, en variables declaradas **dentro de una función**. En variables *globales* (y, a partir de C11, su variante: variables `_Thread_local`), el comportamiento es distinto: si no se indica ningún valor, **se rellenan automáticamente a `0`**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global;
_Thread_local int tlglobal;

int main( void ) {
  printf( "%d %d\n", global, tlglobal );

  return 0;
}
```

> 0 0

Así que, si quieres garantizar el contenido inicial de tus variables, no tienes mas remedio que asignarles tú mismo un valor.

#### Formaciones

Para las formaciones, es posible utilizar un *atajo* para inicializarlas:

- Podemos inicialiar **todos** los elementos:

  ```
  int arr[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  ```
- Podemos inicializar **algunos**, en cuyo caso el resto **queda sin inicializar, con valor aleatorio**:

  ```
  int arr[10] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  ```

  En este caso, solo los elementos `arr[0]` , `arr[1]` y `arr[2]` reciben un valor.
- Podemos utilizar un método abreviado para inicializarlos **todos**, pero únicamente con el valor `0`:

  ```
  int arr[10] = { 0 };
  ```

En este último caso, **todos las posiciones** se rellenan con `0`. Observa que se ha de utilizar exactamente esa forma: `= { 0 };`. De utilizar otro valor (como en el ejemplo anterior), se inicializaran únicamente el número de elementos que indiquemos.